# Sending SES email from AWS Lambda - Node JS Error "Cannot find module 'nodemailer"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this error message:   "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'nodemailer'"

I Googled, and it says install nodemailer. Can someone tell me where exactly do I install this module? I am new to Lambda.

My Lambda function is below :

```
    var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var ses = new aws.SES();
var s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

Comment: You should install module `nodemailer` in your local, then copy all files and input to lambda

Comment: I am using Windows desktop machine. Should I install nodemailer on my Windows desktop and then copy all files and input to Lambda? How do I copy files into Lambda? I thought Lambda is only for writing code, and no storage.  Could you please give me an example? or step by step guide to do this? THank you.

Comment: you need to package your code with appropriate dependencies and deploy it on lambda using ZIP. More details you can get here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll have to initialize your project locally `npm init`
2. Install **nodemailer** - `npm i nodemailer`
3. You should zip your project directory, upload it to lambda by selecting **Upload a .ZIP file** in the **function code** window.
4. Now you'll get an option to test.
5. Just put all the code in `index.js` for your initial tests, later you can move it around.

Comment: Thanks bro for the detailed steps, it really worked for me :)  Glad to set up my first Lambda function. I am trying to send out a test email when a SQS message arrives. Hope I can do it

Comment: I changed to an Ubuntu local server and did all the above steps 1-4. Step 5 done on AWS Web console