# Is it possible to reuse the existing classic load balancers for my new EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is this possible to reuse ELBs so that I can save money.

I have 12 running instances , and 20 ELBs ( some are classic ELB and others application ELB)

I noticed that in my $900 bill per month, $350 is taken only for ELB. Why so much?

Is there any way to find out unused ELBs? so I can delete them

Comment: *"Why so much?"* Balancers are $18+/month, each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, it's better to bring in Application Load Balancers. You can assign multiple target groups to a single application load balancer. Different instances go in different target groups.

AWS Documentation have all the details required for you to get started:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/index.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Appreciat it.

Comment: Since we are here, can I ask you another question which I posted here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547763/sending-ses-email-from-aws-lambda-node-js-error-cannot-find-module-nodemaile?noredirect=1#comment92034989_52547763

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer if you deem it correct.

Comment: Done. thanks again. Hope you can look at my other question I posted just above this comment :)

Comment: commented there itself.

Comment: Great, thank you so much again :) People like you are a blessing on this forum